# Mod rewrite issue with https, strip www from url

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, strip

we have a url for eg  `https://www.egdomain.com/`  and the ssl is valid for egdomain.com. 
so how can i redirect all the requests from `https://www.egdomain.com/` to `https://egdomain.com/`

the site also has normal http requests which works fine.

I tried the htaccess below but still nothing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_PORT} =443

RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help will e much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these two rules to one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(https?://)www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R=301]
```

But maybe this is a little too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says (emphasis mine):

> `RewriteCond` backreferences: These are backreferences of the form %N (1 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the **last matched** `RewriteCond` in the current set of conditions.

So:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that if your certificate is only valid for the variant without `www.`, visitors will still get a security warning when accessing the `www.` variant.